# How does the DOM represent nodes?

Tags: html, dom

How does the DOM represent nodes corresponding to different HTML elements?

e.g:

```
<span>foo</span>

<div>foo</div>
```

Is the DOM representation *exactly* the same for both of these elements, but one of the them has a display property set to inline and the other to block?

In other words - is there actually only a single type of DOM node with lots of properties, or are there actually different DOM nodes corresponding to HTML elements of differing types?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `span` element implements the `HTMLSpanElement` interface, a `div` element the `HTMLDivElement` interface. The elements have different tag names and some other differences. For example, the `div` element has the `align` property, which reflects the `align` attribute (which, despite being declared deprecated in HTML 4 and obsolete in HTML5, is still very much supported and this can be seen in the DOM, too).

All nodes that correspond to HTML elements are `HTMLElement` objects, which are also `Element` objects, but they are also objects of different kinds.

Elements need not have any default rendering. In practice browsers of course have default renderings, but other software processing HTML documents need not have. And in practice browsers implement the “expected rendering” specified in HTML5, and this means e.g. having `display: block` for `div`. However, this is part of a browser’s default stylesheet, at least conceptually, and need not be reflected in the DOM node for the element at all.

Comment: Is it correct to say that a style like `text-align` controls the rendering of the `textNode` created inside in the tree corresponding to something like `<div>foo</div>`?

Comment: The computed value of the `text-align` property (which depends on many things, mostly outside the DOM node of the element) sets the alignment of text lines in the element content. The text is `textNode` nodes in the DOM, but the text nodes have no rendering of their own; they are just part of the content.